# HP LaserJet Pro MFP M28a: unable to reach the scanner from XSane under Debian 11 using HPLIP

Tags: debian, scanner, hp, sane, hplip

My OS is Debian 11 and my printer is an HP LaserJet Pro MFP M28a.
After the first install using the `hplip` package, both printing and scanning were working fine but, for some reason, I had to reinstall the printer and then the scanner became unreachable from `XSane` at all.

I have tried several options and I either get error message code 9 ("error: SANE: Error during device I/O") or 10 ("error: SANE: Out of memory (code=10)") when trying to launch XSane.
Is it actually an error from XSane or from the whole configuration on my computer?

By the way, here is the output from hp-check:

```
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mHP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.2)[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mDependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
hp-check[76380]: info: :This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
hp-check[76380]: info: :This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
hp-check[76380]: info: :under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mNote: hp-check can be run in three modes:[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the
hp-check[76380]: info: :proper dependencies are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.
hp-check[76380]: info: :2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP
hp-check[76380]: info: :supplied tarball has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.
hp-check[76380]: info: :3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time
hp-check[76380]: info: :dependencies).
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :Check types:
hp-check[76380]: info: :a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies
hp-check[76380]: info: :b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)
hp-check[76380]: info: :c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies
hp-check[76380]: info: :d. [All are run-time checks]
hp-check[76380]: info: :PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :Status Types:
hp-check[76380]: info: : OK
hp-check[76380]: info: : MISSING - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
hp-check[76380]: info: : INCOMPAT - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version
hp-check[76380]: info: :
warning: [01mdebian-11 version is not supported. Using debian-10.7 versions dependencies to verify and install...[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :---------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| SYSTEM INFO |
hp-check[76380]: info: :---------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: : Kernel: 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) GNU/Linux
 Host: Aragorn
 Proc: 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) GNU/Linux
 Distribution: debian 11
hp-check[76380]: info: : Bitness: 64 bit

hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :-----------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
hp-check[76380]: info: :-----------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.21.2
hp-check[76380]: info: :HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is not supported for debian distro 11 version
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mCurrent contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :# hplip.conf. Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.21.2

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.21.2
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no
class-driver=no

hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mCurrent contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.21.2

hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mCurrent contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[fax]
email_address =
voice_phone =

[installation]
date_time = 08/16/21 17:03:40
version = 3.21.2

[last_used]
device_uri = escl:http://127.0.0.1:60001
printer_name = Imprimante
working_dir = .

[polling]
device_list =
enable = false
interval = 5

[refresh]
enable = true
rate = 30
type = 1

[settings]
systray_messages = 0
systray_visible = 1

[upgrade]
last_upgraded_time = 1607445828
notify_upgrade = true
pending_upgrade_time = 0

hp-check[76380]: info: : <Package-name> <Package-Desc> <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status> <Comment>
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :-------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| External Dependencies |
hp-check[76380]: info: :-------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[31;01m error: cups CUPS - Common Unix Printing System REQUIRED 1.1 - INCOMPAT 'CUPS may not be installed or not running'[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: : gs GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED 7.05 9.53.3 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : xsane xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE OPTIONAL 0.9 0.999 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : scanimage scanimage - Shell scanning program OPTIONAL 1.0 1.0.31 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : dbus DBus - Message bus system REQUIRED - 1.12.20 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : policykit PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework OPTIONAL - 0.105 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : network network -wget OPTIONAL - 1.21 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : avahi-utils avahi-utils OPTIONAL - 0.8 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| General Dependencies |
hp-check[76380]: info: :------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: : libjpeg libjpeg - JPEG library REQUIRED - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : cups-devel CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files REQUIRED - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : cups-image CUPS image - CUPS image development files REQUIRED - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : libpthread libpthread - POSIX threads library REQUIRED - b'2.31' OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : libusb libusb - USB library REQUIRED - 1.0 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : sane SANE - Scanning library REQUIRED - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : sane-devel SANE - Scanning library development files REQUIRED - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : libavahi-dev libavahi-dev REQUIRED - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : libnetsnmp-devel libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED 5.0.9 5.9 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : libcrypto libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library REQUIRED - 1.1.1 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3X Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language REQUIRED 2.2 3.9.2 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3-notify2 Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL - - OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: :[31;01m error: python3-pyqt4-dbus PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4 OPTIONAL 4.0 - MISSING 'python3-pyqt4-dbus needs to be installed'[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[31;01m error: python3-pyqt4 PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x) REQUIRED 4.0 - MISSING 'python3-pyqt4 needs to be installed'[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3-dbus Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus REQUIRED 0.80.0 1.2.16 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3-xml Python XML libraries REQUIRED - 2.2.10 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3-devel Python devel - Python development files REQUIRED 2.2 3.9.2 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3-pil PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL - 8.1.2 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : python3-reportlab Reportlab - PDF library for Python OPTIONAL 2.0 3.5.59 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :--------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| COMPILEDEP |
hp-check[76380]: info: :--------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: : libtool libtool - Library building support services REQUIRED - 2.4.6 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : gcc gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler REQUIRED - 10.2.1 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : make make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs REQUIRED 3.0 4.3 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :---------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| Python Extentions |
hp-check[76380]: info: :---------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: : cupsext CUPS-Extension REQUIRED - 3.21.2 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: : hpmudext IO-Extension REQUIRED - 3.21.2 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :----------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| Scan Configuration |
hp-check[76380]: info: :----------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :'/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hpaio' not found.
hp-check[76380]: info: : hpaio HPLIP-SANE-Backend REQUIRED - 3.21.2 OK 'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
hp-check[76380]: info: : scanext Scan-SANE-Extension REQUIRED - 3.21.2 OK -
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :------------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
hp-check[76380]: info: :------------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60001' is a HP LaserJet MFP M28a (A7B2AA) (USB) flatbed scanner
device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31?serial=VNC3R77190' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31 all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/hp_laserjet_mfp_m28-m31?ip=127.0.0.1&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard hp_laserjet_mfp_m28-m31 all-in-one
device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60001' is a HP LaserJet MFP M28a (A7B2AA) (USB) flatbed scanner
device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31?serial=VNC3R77190' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31 all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/hp_laserjet_mfp_m28-m31?ip=127.0.0.1&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard hp_laserjet_mfp_m28-m31 all-in-one

hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :--------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
hp-check[76380]: info: :--------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: : Device URI Model
hp-check[76380]: info: : ------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: : hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31?serial=VNC3R77190 HP LaserJet MFP M28-M31
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :---------------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
hp-check[76380]: info: :---------------------------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01m[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01m[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :Type: Unknown
hp-check[76380]: info: :Device URI: implicitclass://HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28a_A7B2AA_USB_/
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01m[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01m[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :Type: Printer
hp-check[76380]: info: :Device URI: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31?serial=VNC3R77190
hp-check[76380]: info: :Communication status: Good
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :--------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| PERMISSION |
hp-check[76380]: info: :--------------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :USB Imprimante Required - - OK Node:'/dev/bus/usb/001/006' Perm:' root lp rw- rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :-----------
hp-check[76380]: info: :| SUMMARY |
hp-check[76380]: info: :-----------
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mMissing Required Dependencies[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01m-----------------------------[0m
error: 'cups' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-pyqt4' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01mMissing Optional Dependencies[0m
hp-check[76380]: info: :[01m-----------------------------[0m
error: 'python3-dbus.mainloop.qt' package is missing/incompatible
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :Total Errors: 3
hp-check[76380]: info: :Total Warnings: 0
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :
hp-check[76380]: info: :Done.
```

I know there is some warning telling me Debian 11 is *not supported* and that some required packages are *missing* (and I did not remove them since then), but I **did manage** to make the scanner work at first, so there must be a way to get it back running (without messing too much with the packages).

Comment: I could not create an `xsane` tag so I chose to use the `sane` one as the closest match.

Comment: It's telling you that the "missing" packages are required for `hplib`/`XSane` to work.

Comment: @waltinator: As I said, I managed to make it work **without** bothering with these error messages. The dependencies are meant for Debian 10.7 and I am using Debian 11. Hence the inconsistency in the error messages. Nevertheless, I do have all packages `cups` 2.3.3op2-3+deb11u1, `libcups` 2.3.3op2-3+deb11u1, `python3-pyqt5` (and *not* Qt4) 5.15.2+dfsg-3 and `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` 2.24.33-2 installed properly on my computer.

Comment: I've just provided a driverless workaround [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665042/205892) but I am still interested in finding an actual way to use the HPLIP solution as well...

Answer (score 1):

A possible first workaround (i.e. not using the full power of the HPLIP solution) is to use an independently developed driverless backend which is `sane-airscan`, as described in [Section 2.2.2.2 of the Debian 11 release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#driverless-operation). After installing the package of the same name, I just had to use the eSCL protocol version of my scanner in the list provided at XSane opening.

`scanimage -L` might be a useful commandline to check whether that new special version of your scanner becomes indeed available or not after installing `sane-airscan`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using escl:http://localhost:60001 instead of escl:http://127.0.0.1:60001 . The latter now returns a HTTP redirect to http://localhost, which the escl backend does not handle.

Comment: I don't know how to configure that within the HPLIP Toolbox. There, I just have access to the command launching xsane (`/usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%` in my case). So far, if I clic on the HPLIP Toolbox icon that launches it, I receive the following error: "Error opening peripheral 'hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M28-M31?serial=VNC3R77190': input/output error on the peripheral." (broadly translated from French)